# How to prove that this function is convex?

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

I want to prove convexity the following function (a,x > 0):
$$
f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{e^{-ax} + ax -1}}
$$
**What I tried:**
Using the Taylor series of $e^{-ax}$
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sum_{i=2}^\infty (-ax)^i/i!}
$$
and $f(x) = 1/\sqrt{g(x)}$ is convex if and only if
$$
f''(x) = \frac{3}{8}g(x)^{5/2}\left(2g'(x)^2-g(x)g''(x)\right) > 0
$$
The following wolframalpha input suggests the convexity:

> (2*(d/dx ((exp(-a*x)+a*x-1)/x^2))^2 - ((exp(-a*x)+a*x-1)/x^2)*d^2/dx^2
>   ((exp(-a*x)+a*x-1)/x^2))
>
> plot (2 e^(-2 a x) (-a x+e^(a x) (2-a x)-2)^2)/x^6-(e^(-a x) (a
>   x+e^(-a x)-1) (a^2 x^2+4 a x+2 e^(a x) (a x-3)+6))/x^6 with x from 0
>   to 1 and a from 0 to 1

Still, this has not helped me out.

Comment: "Concave" in the title, "convexity" in the body of the question...this is why many books use "upwards" and "downwards" convex (concave), to avoid misunderstandings. So which one did you "really" mean?

Comment: And the WA input is almost utterly unreadable...

Comment: I changed the title. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

I think that your life could be easier if you start replacing $x$ by $y/a$. Then, and I shall let you establishing the second derivative (do not forget to simplify as much as possible), the problem of concavity reduces to the analysis of the sign of $$y^2+y \sinh (y)-4 \cosh (y)+4$$ If this quantity is positive, then the function is concave; otherwise, it is convex.

Comment: ya,you may need to do $g'''(y)$ to make sure $g(y)\ge 0 $

Comment: You did not say what was your intent using Taylor series. I think you could have a look to the complete series for $f(y)$,

Comment: sorry to put $g(y)$ to cause misunderstanding.I fully agree your solution which is the same way I think. I try to give a hint for op that take your function go further.(I should put comments on question .:P)

Comment: I agree with you ! This is not the way to work the problem. I am working it now ! Cheers.

Comment: I differentiated $h(y):=f(y/a)$ four times: $$h^{(4)}(y)=C \left(-e^y (y^2+5y+8) + 8e^{2y} \right) >8C\left(-e^y\left(\sum_{i=0}\frac{y^i}{i!}\right)+e^{2y}\right)=0,\,\,C>0$$ for all $y>0$. Then using $h^{(3)}(0) = 0$, it follows that $h^{(3)}(y)$ is strictly positive for $y>0$. This in turn implies convexity of $h''$. So no need to use sinh or cosh. Thanks anyway for the hint of replacing $x$!

Comment: I am glad you made it ! Cheers.

Comment: Found some mistakes. Using a similar procedure as described in the previous comment proves *concavity* of $h(y)$ and so $f(x)$.